# Opencv write Video is running but the saved output.avi file is 0KB

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have tried different methods but none of them works.
As video is running but and file output.avi is empty.

Here is code

```
import cv2
vid=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if (not vid.isOpened()):
    print 'Error'
size = (int(vid.get(3)), int(vid.get(4)))
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')
newVideo=cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,360))
while(vid.isOpened()):
    ret,frame=vid.read()
    if ret is True:
       
        frame=cv2.flip(frame,0)
    
        newVideo.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF==ord('q'):
            break
    
    else:
        break
vid.release()
newVideo.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Any idea where the issue might be? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple, you are reading frame but you are trying to write them in a different size.

The solution is inside of your code. You defined:

```
size = (int(vid.get(3)), int(vid.get(4)))
```

But you didn't use it as like:

```
newVideo=cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,size)
```

You set the sizes as manually(640,360) which is not the size of captured frames.

Comment: Still same issue avi file size is 0kb

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that the output frame's dimension and initialized `VideoWriter` dimensions are the same.

```py
cv2.resize(frame, (640, 360))
```

But, I'm not sure you are using `python3`. Since `print 'Error'` and `fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')` are not `python3` statements.

For `python2` the answer will be:

---

```py
# Add true at the and of the parameter for specifying the frames are RGB.
newVideo = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 360), True) 
.
.
if ret is True:
    frame=cv2.flip(frame,0)
    
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 360))  # missing statement

    newVideo.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    .
    .
```

For `python3` the answer will be:

---

```py
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not vid.isOpened():
    print('Error')

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
newVideo = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 360), True)

while vid.isOpened():
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 0)

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 360))

        newVideo.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vid.release()
newVideo.release()
```

Comment: Still file size is 0kb I have changed as you said but same 0kb file is showing.

Comment: I can assure I've tested the code before posting here. But what is your python version?

Comment: My python version is Python 2.7

Comment: Ok, then let me check again. Since I've tested on python3.7

Comment: Where is your video saved  in directory

Comment: In my directory saved video output.avi file is empty 0kb or somewhere else is it saved which I don't know

Comment: Could you please try with replace `newVideo` variable with this one -> `newVideo=cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,360), True)` and try running again. Maybe the issue is we did not define the color frames

Comment: DO this program works at your console is it showing video in 2.7 if yes. Then it would be my pc fault I think